# JSF 'TAGS' Component

Tags: jsf, tags

*I know the title is slightly misleading but I can't think of a better one right now!*

Im looking for a JSF component that offers the same functionality as the 'Tags' bar used here on stackoverflow when you ask a question.

Its basically a text field that is linked to a `List` where the list values are separated by a space. I know Primefaces offers a 'Tag Cloud' component but thats really not what I'm looking for.

**NB**. *If no such component exists I'm happy to go ahead and try and create one if somebody could point me to some good tutorials on creating custom JSF components.*

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was right under my nose all along.

[Primefaces AutoComplete - Multiple Selection](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteMultiple.jsf;jsessionid=1kweozsevpe0f12h84wh98iosk)